# Canvas animation speed

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am putting together a simulation of an urban transportation system, and trying to improve my Javascript and Canvas skills. I have provided a bare-bones version here: https://jsfiddle.net/ftmzm9vp/

Two questions:

1) I want the "pods" to run at a uniform rate. Right now they are all arriving at their destinations at the same time, which means they are traveling at different speeds. How do I correct this?

2) There is obviously more I have to do -- get the pods to travel along existing lines, work out the best path to their destination, expand the number of lines and stations -- all of which will increase the computing overhead. Right now, with the 500 pods I want to use, the animation is starting to crawl. I rewrote the whole thing to use requestAnimFrame, as I thought it would be faster, but it doesn't seem to be as smooth at it should be. What can I do to improve this? 
Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<title>Pod Stations Lines Test</title>
<body>
    <canvas id="layer1" style="z-index: 2;  
                position:absolute;
                left:0px;
                top:0px;
                " height="600px" width="1000">This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.</canvas>
    <canvas id="layer2" style="z-index: 3;
                position:absolute;
                left:0px;
                top:0px;
                " height="600px" width="1000">This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.</canvas>
    <canvas id="layer3" style="z-index: 1;
                position:absolute;
                left:0px;
                top:0px;
                " height="600px" width="1000">This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.</canvas>
    <script>
        //Modified Source: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/HAbfm/
        //
        layer1 = document.getElementById("layer1");
        ctx1 = layer1.getContext("2d");
        layer2 = document.getElementById("layer2");
        ctx2 = layer2.getContext("2d");
        layer3 = document.getElementById("layer3");
        ctx3 = layer3.getContext("2d");

        window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
            return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || function(callback) {
                window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
            };
        })();

        //STATION LIST
        var station = [
            ['A', 100, 50],
            ['B', 300, 50],
            ['C', 200, 150],
            ['D', 100, 250],
            ['E', 300, 250],
            ['F', 400, 250]
        ];


        //DRAW LINES
        function drawLines() {

            ctx1.clearRect(0, 0, layer3.width, layer3.height);

            var linkAB = ctx1.beginPath();
            ctx1.moveTo(station[0][1], station[0][2]);
            ctx1.lineTo(station[1][1], station[1][2]);
            ctx1.stroke();
            var linkBC = ctx1.beginPath();
            ctx1.moveTo(station[1][1], station[1][2]);
            ctx1.lineTo(station[2][1], station[2][2]);
            ctx1.stroke();
            var linkCD = ctx1.beginPath();
            ctx1.moveTo(station[2][1], station[2][2]);
            ctx1.lineTo(station[3][1], station[3][2]);
            ctx1.stroke();
            var linkDE = ctx1.beginPath();
            ctx1.moveTo(station[3][1], station[3][2]);
            ctx1.lineTo(station[4][1], station[4][2]);
            ctx1.stroke();
            var linkCE = ctx1.beginPath();
            ctx1.moveTo(station[2][1], station[2][2]);
            ctx1.lineTo(station[4][1], station[4][2]);
            ctx1.stroke();
            var linkEF = ctx1.beginPath();
            ctx1.moveTo(station[4][1], station[4][2]);
            ctx1.lineTo(station[5][1], station[5][2]);
            ctx1.stroke();

        }


        //CREATE PODS

        var podArray = [];

        function Pod(startX, startY, endX, endY, riders, color) {
            this.startX = startX;
            this.startY = startY;
            this.endX = endX;
            this.endY = endY;
            this.riders = riders;
            this.color = color;
        }

        var colorArray = ["gold", "orange", "red", "green", "blue", "black"];

        function randomPass() {
            occ = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
            return occ;
            console.log("Riders " + occ);
        }


        for (i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            var origNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * station.length);
            var origin = {
                x: station[origNum][1],
                y: station[origNum][2]
            }
            var destNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * station.length);
            while (origNum == destNum) {
                destNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * station.length);
            }
            var destination = {
                x: station[destNum][1],
                y: station[destNum][2]
            }

            podArray.push(new Pod(
            startX = origin.x,
            startY = origin.y,
            endX = destination.x,
            endY = destination.y,
            riders = randomPass(),
            color = colorArray[riders - 1]

            ));
        }

        var pct = 0.00;
        var fps = 60;

        //CALL DRAWING AND ANIMATION
        drawLines();
        animate();

        function animate() {
            setTimeout(function() {

                if (pct <= 1.00) {
                    requestAnimFrame(animate)
                };

                // increment the percent (from 0.00 to 1.00)
                pct += .01;

                // clear the canvas
                ctx3.clearRect(0, 0, layer3.width, layer3.height);

                // draw all podArray
                for (var i = 0; i < podArray.length; i++) {

                    // get reference to next aPod
                    var aPod = podArray[i];

                    var dx = aPod.endX - aPod.startX;
                    var dy = aPod.endY - aPod.startY;
                    var nextX = aPod.startX + dx * pct;
                    var nextY = aPod.startY + dy * pct;

                    //create pod on screen
                    ctx3.fillStyle = aPod.color;
                    ctx3.beginPath();
                    ctx3.arc(nextX, nextY, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
                    ctx3.fillStyle = aPod.color;
                    ctx3.fill();
                    ctx3.closePath();

                    //STATION LETTERS

                    for (s = 0; s < station.length; s++) {
                        ctx2.font = '12pt Calibri';
                        ctx2.fillStyle = 'red';
                        ctx2.textAlign = 'center';
                        ctx2.fillText(station[s][0], station[s][1], (station[s][2]) + 4);
                    }

                }

            }, 1000 / fps);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your vehicles all reach their destination at the same time because you are changing their position based on a percentage. So when pct==1.00 all vehicles arrive simultaneously at their own endpoints regardless of the distance they need to travel to get there.

```
// increment the percent (from 0.00 to 1.00)
pct += .01;
```

**To make a vehicle arrive based on distance traveled**

Question#1: You can calculate each waypoint (waypoint==unique pixel) the vehicle must travel to complete it's route. Advance the vehicle to it's next waypoint with each new animation frame. This causes each vehicle to arrive based on the length of their route rather than a uniform percentage.

Question#2: For each vehicle, if you pre-calculate & save its waypoints into an array, you can easily get 500 vehicles drawn on the canvas during each animation frame.

**Here's annotated and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

ctx.lineWidth=2;

// define routes
var routes=[];
routes.push({
  points:linePoints({x:10,y:10},{x:150,y:10}),
  currentPoint:0,
  color:'red',
});
routes.push({
  points:linePoints({x:10,y:50},{x:250,y:65}),
  currentPoint:0,
  color:'green',
});
routes.push({
  points:linePoints({x:10,y:90},{x:325,y:105}),
  currentPoint:0,
  color:'blue',
});

// animation related vars
var lastTime=0;
var delay=1000/60*5;

// start animating
requestAnimationFrame(animate);

function animate(time){
  // return if the desired time hasn't elapsed
  if(time<lastTime){requestAnimationFrame(animate);return;}
  // redraw each route
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  // var used to stop animating if all routes are completed
  var isComplete=true;
  for(var i=0;i<routes.length;i++){
    var r=routes[i];
    // increase the currentPoint, but not beyond points.length-1
    if((r.currentPoint+1)<r.points.length-1){
      isComplete=false;
      r.currentPoint++;
    }
    // draw the route to its current point
    ctx.strokeStyle=r.color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(r.points[0].x,r.points[0].y);
    ctx.lineTo(r.points[r.currentPoint].x,r.points[r.currentPoint].y);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fillStyle=r.color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(r.points[r.currentPoint].x,r.points[r.currentPoint].y,5,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fill();
  }
  // request another frame unless all routes are completed
  if(!isComplete){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }
}

function linePoints(p1,p2){
  // start building a points array with the starting point
  var points=[p1];
  var dx=p2.x-p1.x;
  var dy=p2.y-p1.y;
  var count=Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy)*3;
  for(var pct=0;pct<count;pct++){
    // calc next waypoint on the line
    var x=p1.x+dx*pct/count;
    var y=p1.y+dy*pct/count;
    var lastPt=points[points.length-1];
    // add new waypoint if the its integer pixel value has
    // changed from last waypoint
    if(parseInt(x)!==parseInt(lastPt.x) || parseInt(y)!==parseInt(lastPt.y)){
      points.push({x:x,y:y});
    }
  }
  // force the last point to be the ending point
  points[points.length-1]=p2;
  // return a unique points[] forming a line from p1 to p2
  return(points);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=350 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Still trying to get the logic of canvas. Thank you for this!

Comment: I tried adapting your code, but can't get it to draw anything to the screen. What have I missed? [link]( https://jsfiddle.net/yL8udg9r/)

Answer (score 1):

To make your pods go the same speed you will probably want to use the Pythagorean theorem. Hypotenuse is the distance you want the node to travel each time the rAF comes around. Then calculate your x's and y's from that.

I'm not quite sure if I understand what `pct` does.

To speed up the rAF you'll want to:

1. kill your set timeout
2. prerender

Prerending is a bit more work but instead of drawing each circle each and every time you have canvases that aren't in the DOM that you draw to. Then you essentially lay the 'hidden' canvas where ever you want on top of the visible DOM canvas. It keeps the drawing in memory this way.

You also draw each circle on the canvas at the end of the for-loop. Pull the fill method outside of it this way the canvas can batch draw instead of a bunch of little calls (this can really kill performance).

Setting font stuff each time can be removed.

Canvas is awesome for performance but you just have to be careful because one small mistake can lead to a huge bottle-neck.

This is a good article: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/performance/

Lemme know if you have any more questions.

Comment: I will look into this. I had seen it before, but had not tried to implement it.